# Gemfile template

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, rails

I'm trying to modify the default gemfile template on debian, and it doesn't seem to be anywhere to be found. Is this found somewhere on the system called "Gemfile" or is it located in another directory. I've used find, and grep to search the system, and even similar looking files don't seem to effect a newly generated rails apps. Is there any way to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: Actually....I just answered my own question. I found a file located at 

    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates

The confusing part was that it doesn't include everything in the output "Gemfile" from the newly generated rails app, but editing it does include my new requirements.

Comment: Note that you can answer your own question in a few hours from now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I found the answer on my own. the file located at

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile
```

Is actually the file you need to modify. It does not have everything else contained in your output file, only some of it. If you append anything to it, it will appear in your Gemfile though.